# codeigniter 3.11 global variable array in constants.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, constants, global-variables

How can i declare a global array in constants.php?

I want use an array of this form in a helper file.

```
$process['up_position']['Title']='Up position';
$process['up_position']['icon']='icon-up';
$process['up_position']['description']='Up a position';

$process['down_position']['Title']='Down position';
$process['down_position']['icon']='icon-down';
$process['down_position']['description']='Down a position';
```

What is the better way?

Thank you!!

I see constants.php but all constants are simple values

Comment: Global Variables are a bit sticky to 'assume' work in CI, the easiest way I can think of is to put it in the CI_Controller construct as $this->process and refer to it in your code that way.

Comment: You could create your own config file. Then autoload the config file in autoload.php `$autoload['config'] = array('myconfig');`

Answer (score 0):

Constants are simple values in general. These are values that never change.
My own opinion is

1. Option 1 : to have these in the Config file if they are system wide settings.
2. Option 2 : to have them in a table if you ever want to change them.
3. Option 3 : to have them in the super class of your Controller or Model so you have them inherited in every file you create, you don't need to assign them anymore but just use them as they are.
4. Option 4 : to have them in a library.

It all depends where you read / use them from. I see you have "title", "icon" and "description" so these seem to be objects used in a view, I'd assume. Then you can create a controller super class where objects like that are created, you just assign the values to them once you call the view and the view will have the values.

Comment: Thank you very much Marius, Forbs and Rager!!  I have used a config file as Ragger suggest. I read this values in a view_helper. My view pass the confg to the helper because the helper  cannot read the values. Sorry for my english!!